# If statement nested in for loop

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a program that prints "-" if the number is divisible by 2 and "*" if it is not. I get it to print the numbers, - and *, but it is not printing - and * in place of the number, if that makes sense?

```
public class Exercise2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(int i = 100; i <= 200; i++) {
            if(i % 2 == 0){
                System.out.println("-");
            } else {
                System.out.println("*");
            }
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }

}
```

I can't understand where exactly I'm going wrong. Any help is appreciated and thank you in advance.

Comment: Use `print` (not `println`).

Comment: You have to remove the `System.out.println(i);` if you do not want to print the number itself.

Comment: If you don't want the numbers, you can remove `System.out.println(i);`

Comment: Are you trying to get it to print all on the same line? Can you provide some sample output that you are expecting (or perhaps a few examples of how the program should progress)?

Comment: Your question is unclear, show the output you are getting and the output you expect.

Comment: So, for example the output would be: 
100
101
102 

etc with the numbers replaced by the symbols. Basically print the symbol in place of the number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you dont want to print the numbers you can just remove `System.out.println(i);` from your original answer and it should work fine.

If you want to print the symbol and the number in the same line it can be done by changing the `System.out.println()` to `System.out.print()`.

```
public class Exercise2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(int i = 100; i <= 200; i++) {
            if(i % 2 == 0){
                System.out.print("- ");
            } else {
                System.out.print("* ");
            }
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

The answer above will print the numbers in this fassion:

```
- 100
* 101
- 102
* 103
- 104
* 105
- 106
...
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. It isn't what I asked for, but I think this would look much better anyway.

Comment: You are welcome. Sorry if it isnt exactly what you where expecting as the question was a bit unclear, so I gave you the two answers that you could may be looking for, the first one just printing the symbols and the seconds one ( with the code ) is the one with both symbols as numbers.